# export entire stata table to latex

Tags: latex, stata

I have used `esttab` before to export regression results to Stata. However I have build a small table that I would like to export as it is:

**Sample Data**

```
* create a fake table with data to be exported to tex
sysuse auto, clear
keep make price mpg rep78 headroom
keep if _n < 20
```

Is there an easy way to have the data put into an latex-table? I can live without the variable names, but if labels can be exported even better.

Cross posted on [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1627203-export-entire-dataset-to-latex).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The community-contributed `texsave` appears to be made for precisely this. It has a `varlabels` option to write labels in the header instead of variable names.

```
ssc install texsave
texsave * using whatever.tex, varlabels
```

If you want to keep only the `tabularx` part it's a bit harder, `texsave` doesn't seem to provide a way to do that. I see three options:

1. Write your own code that produces the tex file you want
2. Adjust `texsave.ado` to produce the file you want
3. Adjust the output you get from `texsave`

The code below does the latter.

```
* create a fake table with data to be exported to tex
sysuse auto, clear
keep make price mpg rep78 headroom
keep if _n < 20

texsave * using whatever.tex, varlabels frag replace

import delimited using whatever.tex, clear
gen keep = strpos(v1, "{tabularx}") > 0
replace keep = cond(keep == 1, keep, sum(keep))
keep if keep == 1
drop keep
export delimited using whatever.tex, novarnames replace
```

You could still manually insert lines you want, for example with `insobs`, or adjust certain lines with `replace`.

Comment: almost perfect. Using `frag` one can drop the document headers, but ideally one could limit everything to the insides of `tabularx`. Any idea?